# What should I do when I change the status to graphql mutation?

Tags: graphql, graphql-mutation

there is member schema like following

```
type Member {
   is_deleted
}
```

when i change only is_deleted field, what is the best practice change that field

1. using updateMember mutation that can modify all fields
2. using another changeDeleteStatus mutation that can only change is_delete status

please give me the insight

Answer (score 0):

For performance the two has no significant difference. But for me i would use the current updateMember function so that I wont create a new function just for that one operation.

Comment: in apollo, https://blog.apollographql.com/designing-graphql-mutations-e09de826ed97 
Caleb Meredith said **Specificity. Make mutations as specific as possible. Mutations should represent semantic actions that might be taken by the user whenever possible.**.  what do you think about this?